# DATATABLE Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

Tags: php, html, datatables

issue getting in datatable while i m using loop array
Column are equal thead and tbody still getting issue.
i m faching data from command and using array i want output in datatable.output is working but datable shorting and search option is not working.

```
<div class="m-t-25">
  <table id="data-table" class="table dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($output[0] as $clave=>$fila) {
          echo "<th>".$fila."</th>";
        }
        ?>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $output = array_slice($output, 2); 
    foreach ($output as $fila) {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($fila as $elemento) {
        echo "<td>".$elemento."</td>";
      }
      echo '<td><select class="act">';
      echo '<option value="watch" selected="">graph</option>';
      echo '</select></td>';
      echo "</tr>";
    } 
    ?>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: You're missing a `<?php` before the second `foreach`. (The syntax highlighting makes it pretty obvious).

Comment: still same issue

Comment: This suggests the error occurs only when one of the column titles is blank: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined, or the number of columns doesn't match your definition in datatables (which you haven't shown here). It also suggests a couple of other possibilities. We can't tell what's going wrong, based on what you've shown here, because we lack the finished HTML (we can't predict what the PHP will generate, without the source data) and we lack your datatables configuration code. Try to make a [mre] of the issue.